# Blender could not convert the .blend file to FBX file

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, blend

Unity cant import .blend files.
Blender version 2.74 is installed, try to reinstall - did not help,

He writes error:
`Blender could not convert the .blend file to FBX file.
You need to use Blender 2.45-2.49 or 2.58 and later versions for direct Blender import to work.
UnityEditorInternal.InternalEditorUtility:ProjectWindowDrag(HierarchyProperty, Boolean)
UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()`

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't meant as a software support community. If you're having trouble with either Unity or Blender you're better off contacting them or their support communities.

Comment: First try manually opening the blend file in blender and exporting it to fbx, maybe the fbx exporter is disabled or something in the file is breaking the export? Also try 2.73 or 2.72 if there is an issue with the latest version. Try [blender.stackexchange.com](http://blender.stackexchange.com) for blender help and [answers.unity3d.com](http://answers.unity3d.com/) for unity.

Answer (score 1):

Running Unity as Administrator solved the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you export your blender file to a .fbx file and try to import that?

Comment: yes .fbx im import easy, but i need to import .blend

Comment: Why does it need to be .blend?

Comment: I believe Unity should be able to import a blend file, but behind the scenes it automatically tells blender to do the export to fbx.